# Dice Distance returning nan. Workaround?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, categorical-data, feature-selection, distance, feature-engineering

**Starting Point:**
I want to calculate the distances between nominal data. Furthermore, I want to see what difference it makes to only use important features (given some feature selection method). So I calculated the Hamming Distance with important nominal Features.
I now want to discover what happens if I create dummy variables (one-hot encoding) and calculate the distance between *only important dummy variables*.

I tried out the dice distance as it yields the **same distance** for dummies as the hamming distance for nominal data **when using all features**.

The Dice distance is calculated by: $D(x,y) =1- \frac{2a}{2a+b+c}$,

where a: number of times x and y equal 1

b: number of times x = 1 and y = 0

c: number of times x = 0 and y = 1

**Problem:**
When taking only the important dummy variables, it can happen that $a = b = c = 0$!. So the Dice Distance returns *Nan*.

So what is the distance between two observations whose important dummy variables are all equal to zero? Is it simply 1, because there is no match? Is it 0 because two observations are identical and it should be that $D(x,y) = 0 $ if $ x = y$?

Or are there binary distance measures that are more suitable for this task? I personally liked the dice distance for its comparability with the hamming distance.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with fractions that contain a denominator that may equal to $0$, it is always a good idea to add a very small value to the denominator to avoid dividing by $0$.

For example, in the case of the dice distance, it becomes:

$$
D(x,y) =1- \frac{2a}{2a+b+c + 10^{-9}}
$$

This means that when $a=b=c=0$, then the dice distance will equal $1$. $10^{-9}$ is an arbitrary value here. You can choose smaller values if you want.

Comment: Nevertheless the question remains if that is suitable for the task. Two identical points would know have the maximum distance with does not seem right...

Comment: Your question has several sub-questions. I only answered the first one. What was wrong with using the Hamming distance? Cosine similarity may also be used here